# SwiftData Crash on Launch in iOS 17.4: The configuration named 'default' does not contain any entities

Tags: ios, swift-data

Has anyone seen Swift Data failing to load a store and crashing on launch since iOS 17.4? I saw this happen on my iPhone, and reproduced with my iPad - app launches fine, upgrade to 17.4, now crashes on launch with the error:

```
error: Store failed to load.  <NSPersistentStoreDescription: 0x300488120> (type: SQLite, url: file:///dev/null) with error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "A Core Data error occurred." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The configuration named 'default' does not contain any entities.} with userInfo {
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "The configuration named 'default' does not contain any entities.";
}
CoreData: error: Store failed to load.  <NSPersistentStoreDescription: 0x300488120> (type: SQLite, url: file:///dev/null) with error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "A Core Data error occurred." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The configuration named 'default' does not contain any entities.} with userInfo {
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "The configuration named 'default' does not contain any entities.";
}
Unresolved error loading container Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "A Core Data error occurred." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The configuration named 'default' does not contain any entities.}

...

_SwiftData_SwiftUI/ModelContainer+Extensions.swift:6: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError(_error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError._Error.loadIssueModelContainer)
```

I set up my ModelContainer in my store class like so:

```
    private init() {
        let configuration: ModelConfiguration
            
        configuration = ModelConfiguration(
            isStoredInMemoryOnly: false,
            allowsSave: true,
            groupContainer: .identifier(identifier) // identifier is an App Group Identifier
        )

        do {
            self.container = try ModelContainer(
                for: SDEntry.self, SDTag.self, SDSavedFilter.self,
                configurations: configuration
            )
        } catch let error {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }        
    }
```

It's not actually crashing on the fatalError above, though; it makes it all the way through that initializer fine. At some point later on, it crashes in `_SwiftData_SwiftUI/ModelContainer+Extensions.swift`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: I construct my `ModelContainer` in a separate place from my SwiftUI layer, and previously it seems like it was sufficient for me to inject the ModelContext via `.environment(\.modelContext, <myOwnMainContext>)`, but now I guess I have to actually use `.modelContainer()` or `.modelContext()` to inject those. Switching to `.modelContext(<myOwnMainContext>)` fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same phenomenon after updating to Sonoma 14.4. I'm using Xcode 15.3. Can you please show me a concrete code example. Based on your solution, I can't understand exactly what change you're making and where. That would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was necessary to move the time of the assignment to the end.

Here's an example of my initial situation:

```
var container: ModelContainer
...
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }
    .modelContainer(container) //<-- assigned too early
    .commands {
        PrototypeCommands() //<-- uses the model context too
    }
    //<-- should be assigned here
}
```

**PrototypeCommands()** itself uses the model-context. The time of assignment should therefore only be chosen afterwards:

That ultimately helped:

```
var container: ModelContainer
...
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }  
    .commands {
        PrototypeCommands()
    }
    .modelContainer(container) //<-- in last place
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, the root cause was: where I initialized `ModelContainer`, I used
`@Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext`.

Just avoid using the environment variable `@Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext` before initializing `ModelContainer`, that is, before `XxxView().modelContainer(container)`